# Are there any free or relatively cheap remote classroom software applications?

Tags: collaboration, remote-access

Does anyone know any good free or relatively cheap remote classroom software?

I want to be able to have training sessions with multiple students and have a working session where I can monitor students as they work through exercises and point out flaws or take control to show them how to work through the exercise they are struggling with.

This is different from something like WebEx or GoToMeeting because only one person can share their screen at once. I would want to be the only one to see all screens and then each student would only be able to see one shared screen and their own.

OS: Windows, but Windows and Mac would be better.

Comment: Have you tried [Google Classroom](https://www.google.com/edu/products/productivity-tools/classroom/)? I know there is no collaboration screen sharing but I think it worth a try.

Comment: What OS must it run on? What specific features do you need? The better you describe your needs, the better answers/recommendations can meet them. Currently it's a bit broad as not even the environment (OS) is clear.

Comment: @BálintBabics The screen collaboration is absolutely essential.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking like ScreenLeap.com will meet my needs. Each student can easily just go to that website and click a button and in a matter of 5 seconds start sharing their screen without logging in or creating an account or anything like that.

This will allow us to view each user's screen while they work through the training exercises. It doesn't let us take control of their screen and there might not be any audio but we are already using WebEx for the meeting itself and recording it.

Also, ScreenLeap.com is FREE!